# what does "x = (something)" mean in java?

Tags: java, android, syntax

I learn Android and do not know java (yet), and found this statement in a sample code:

```
TextView mainTextView;
mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
```

So, the question is (as the header says): what does "= ( ... )" mean?

Comment: That is an assignment statement, one of the most basic constructs in Java. I would advise learning at least the basics of the Java language before trying to write Android applications.

Comment: casting one type to other type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creates objectref for Object TextView

```
TextView mainTextView;
```

findViewById is a method having parameter  R.id.main_textview and the returned value is getting casted to TextView type and stored in mainTextView

```
mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the findViewById method is casting the XML element to a TextView.

Comment: not casting XML element to a TextView. casting View to TextView. findViewById returns a View object

Comment: A View is an XML element. It is declared and accessed in the layout files

Comment: A View is a Java Object. XML is used by Android to define values for layouts and other items. XML is not a type of Java Object though.

Comment: @dharms yes you are correct. I merely meant that the object is derived from the XML. findViewById() allows the Android Runtime to populate the correct object based on the given XML parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The method `findViewById` has the following signature:

```
public View findViewById (int id)
```

It means that it returns a generic non-specified `View`.

Because your code apparently needs to work with more specific (in the meaning of class hierarchy) `TextView`, it is *typecasted* to `TextView` by prepending `(TextView)` before the value returned by `findViewById`.

Although it is a common practice, it is kind of dangerous as it *assumes* that the value returned by `findViewById` is in this case of the type `TextView`. If it is not, you will get a runtime exception [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)